# Laravel Image error

Tags: image, laravel

Hello can anyone help me with this problem in laravel?

In local server when I upload image it is working but in live server it is not working because of this problem:

```
[2015-05-22 10:38:23] production.ERROR: exception 'Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException'
```

with message

> Can't write image data to path (/var/www/vhosts/domain-name/httpdocs/mainsource/img/courses/1432291103.jpg)

and if i create a folder inside mainsource `img/courses` image will be saved but doesn't show in the page.

Also i have the same folder `img/courses` in public from which also my courses page reads images and shows images.

Comment: The not writeable part is because the folder either does not exists or you don't have permission to that folder. The fact that it doesn't show on the page is something you need to explain better. There can be a lot of reasons why it doesn't show up. Have you checked the source? Show more code!

Comment: The folder img/courses it is under public folder. And permission I have changed to 777. But when i try to upload in this folder gives me the error, /var/www/vhosts/domain-name/httpdocs/mainsource/img/courses/1432291103.jpg. I dont know why it is giving me the error when I am not trying to upload image under mainsource/img/courses but under public folder img/courses. in Local server works perfect but in live server doesnt work it is looking for mainsource/img/courses which folder doesn't exist in mainsource but this folder is httpdocs/img/courses in mainsource I have private files like   app

Comment: How am I supposed to solve your problem if I don't have exact error messages and code to look at? You need to understand that I need to see specifics: errors and source code.

Comment: Thanks Ortix for your help. But right now I have solved the problem. I have try to write here all my project but here I can not write my code because limitation of letters and i didn't have your email, because i could write to you in your email. But anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you can't expect anyone able to answer your question ;)